# Using .click function in jQuery to direct HTML button to different profiles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have four buttons on my portfolio website.  One directs to linkedin, one to code wars, one to github and one to free code camp.  I have included the html and jQuery for these four buttons below.  After using this code, only the button directing to code wars works, the other three don't open any window at all and I can't figure out why.

```
<button type= button class="btn-block btn-social btn-github">
    <i class="fa fa-github-square"></i> GitHub</button>

<button type=button class="btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i> LinkedIn</button>

<button type=button class="btn-block btn-social btn-codewars">Code Wars</button>

<button type=button class="btn-block btn-social btn-freecodecamp">
    Free Code Camp</button>


$('.btn-codewars').click(function(){
window.location = 'http://www.codewars.com/users/jwianniello' + this.id;
 }); 

$('.btn-github').click(function(){
window.location = 'http://github.com/jwianniello' + this.id;
});    

$('.btn-linkedin').click(function(){
window.location = 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/joe-ianniello-78338690?trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile' + this.id;  
});

$('.btn-freecodecamp').click(function(){ window.location =     'http://www.freecodecamp.com/jwianniello'+ this.id;  
});
```

Comment: Why not just wrap the buttons with forms, and you wouldn't need javascript at all ?

Comment: show us a bit of html too... But yes it's not necessary jQuery you can do it with plain html like `<a href="http://..." target="_blank">`

Comment: @Joe : You `haven't given ids` to any of the buttons in your `HTML`, and you are calling `this.id` in your jquery, which will result in the window being directed to an erroneous `url`.

Comment: why don't use href for the links, also you didn't set any id, but even if you did, you can't access id, with this.id in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not working because you have html errors around `type= button` and second because the `this.id` does not exist. It should be `type="button"` and you have to add the `id` attribute on every `<button>`.

The following code works...

**Note**: Just remember to uncomment the commented code below and remove `console.log(...)` which i added for testing purposes.

**Note 2**: The first link to codewars it is working because you have your username at the end: `http://www.codewars.com/users/jwianniello`

```
<button type="button" id="githubUserName" class="btn-block btn-social btn-github">
    <i class="fa fa-github-square"></i> GitHub
</button>
<button type="button" id="linkedinUserName" class="btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i> LinkedIn
</button>
<button type="button" id="codewarsUserName" class="btn-block btn-social btn-codewars">Code Wars</button>
<button type="button" id="freecodeCampUserName" class="btn-block btn-social btn-freecodecamp">
    Free Code Camp</button>
<script>
    $('.btn-codewars').click(function() {
        console.log("codewars ", this.id);
        //window.location = 'http://www.codewars.com/users/jwianniello' + this.id;
    });

    $('.btn-github').click(function() {
        console.log("github ", this.id);
        //window.location = 'http://github.com/jwianniello' + this.id;
    });

    $('.btn-linkedin').click(function() {
        console.log("linkedin ", this.id);
        //window.location = 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/joe-ianniello-78338690?trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile' + this.id;
    });

    $('.btn-freecodecamp').click(function() {
        console.log("freecodecamp ", this.id);
        //window.location = 'http://www.freecodecamp.com/jwianniello' + this.id;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table tr td {
            border:dotted 2px red;
        }
        .selectedSeat {
        color:blue;
        }
    </style>
<script>



    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.btn-codewars').click(function () {
            window.location = 'http://www.codewars.com/users/jwianniello' + this.id;
        });

        $('.btn-github').click(function () {
            window.location = 'http://github.com/jwianniello' + this.id;
        });

        $('.btn-linkedin').click(function () {
            window.location = 'http://www.linkedin.com/in/joe-ianniello-78338690?trk=nav_responsive_tab_profile' + this.id;
        });

        $('.btn-freecodecamp').click(function () {
            window.location = 'http://www.freecodecamp.com/jwianniello' + this.id;
        });
});
</script>
</head>

<body style="width:50%;">
  <button type= button class="btn-block btn-social btn-github">
    <i class="fa fa-github-square"></i> GitHub</button>

<button type=button class="btn-block btn-social btn-linkedin">
    <i class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></i> LinkedIn</button>

<button type=button class="btn-block btn-social btn-codewars">Code Wars</button>

<button type=button class="btn-block btn-social btn-freecodecamp">
    Free Code Camp</button>
</body>
</html>
```